# does showing tab bar at top violate apple Human Interface Guidelines?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am developing an app on which i want to show a tab bar at the top of the screen.When user tap on tab then it should redirect user to different screen.Normally i see tab bar at bottom.So What will happen if i show tab bar at top.

```
 1.Does it violate apple human interface guidelines?

 2. If i don't follow apple Human Interface Guidelines.Will apple reject my app on app store?
```

Please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking tabs, as in browsers? If so, then no putting your tabs or a tab button in the top of the screen doesn't violate any guidelines. For example, the newly released Firefox for iOS has a tab button in the top right corner.

However, you should generally show how you have tried to find an answer, as the iOS Human Interface Guidelines provide clear guidelines about how you should design your app.

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/)